# Using WEKA J48 classifier for satellite image classifications?

Tags: classification, land-cover

I am trying to build a tool from WEKA software using the J48 classifier for automatic satellite image classification to build landuse land cover maps.

How do I input the satellite image in WEKA after converting it into ASCII format?

Answer (score 1):

WEKA is relatively easy to use. First, convert your training data into [ARFF format](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF). For example, if your satellite data consists of three band values, `(b1,b2,b3)`, and a land cover label, `lc`, then your ARFF format might be:

`@RELATION Example
@ATTRIBUTE b1 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE b2 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE b3 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE lc CLASS {vegetation, water, bare_soils}
@DATA
0.2,0.3,0.1,vegetation
...`

Inside code, assuming you use Java, it's as simple as:

```
    ArffReader arff = new ArffReader(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(INPUT_DATA_ARFF)));

    Instances trainSet = arff.getData();
    trainSet.setClassIndex(trainSet.numAttributes() - 1);

    Classifier decisionTree = new J48();
    decisionTree .buildClassifier(trainSet);

    // evaluation

    // let newUnseenExample be an unlabeled feature vector 
    decisionTree.classify(newUnseenExample)
```

This snippet should help you get started. The art is in choosing the right model and the right representation of your data, of course.